# minesweeper surrounding mines works half the time

Tags: java, minesweeper

I'm writing minesweeper clone in Java, and I've been having some trouble with the part where the surrounding number of bombs are calculated. For some reason, either some cells detect additional bombs, or no bombs at all (even weirdly, some cells work fine). Could someone help? Thanks!

note: `key[][]` is an `int[][]` array that records the locations of the bombs, designated as 9.

0 represents an empty space

`int count` represents the amount of bombs that are in the 8 cells surrounding each cell (that's why I also have 8 try-catch loops to account for the border cells)

ps: sorry for the bad formatting

EDIT: I figured out where my problem was (i called i twice). Any suggestions as to how I could make this code simpler and more efficient?

```
private void numberSet() {

    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < key.length; i++) {
        for (int a = 0; a < key[0].length; a++) {

            if (key[i][a] == 0) {

                try {
                    if (key[i + 1][a] == 9) {
                        count++;
                    }

                } catch (java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                    continue;
                }
                try {
                    if (key[i - 1][a] == 9) {
                        count++;
                    }

                } catch (java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                    continue;
                }
                try {
                    if (key[i][a + 1] == 9) {
                        count++;
                    }

                } catch (java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                    continue;
                }
                try {
                    if (key[i][a - 1] == 9) {
                        count++;
                    }

                } catch (java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                    continue;
                }
                try {
                    if (key[i + 1][a + 1] == 9) {
                        count++;
                    }

                } catch (java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                    continue;
                }
                try {
                    if (key[i - 1][a + 1] == 9) {
                        count++;
                    }

                } catch (java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                    continue;
                }
                try {
                    if (key[i + 1][a - 1] == 9) {
                        count++;
                    }

                } catch (java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                    continue;
                }
                try {
                    if (key[i - 1][i - 1] == 9) {
                        count++;

                    }

                } catch (java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                    continue;
                }
                key[i][a] = count;
            }
            count = 0;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I feel like you should get rid of all the try/catch blocks. It should be coded in such a way that an array index out of bounds cannot happen, and if it does still happen *then* you want an exception thrown so that the program explodes and you know you have not written it correctly.

Comment: a small tip concerning code snippets: if you don't use it already, get yourself a proper IDE - like IntelliJ https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/ - and use "Reformat Code" to bring your code in a good shape before pasting it in a forum or on StackOverflow. If your code is easier to read, people are more likely to help you.

Comment: like test to see if i or a is 0 first?

Comment: That's half of it. You also need to make sure it doesn't go past the array. Like cells at the edge of the grid. If you look at my code below you'll see how I tested for edges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would seriously consider completely abandoning the way you're doing this. When I first started to code, I too made a minesweeper game, and I did what you were doing. After a few revisions, I was able to put all of it into a few loops. I tried to comment enough in my code to tell you what every line does. This code is not tested, so it probably won't work right away to be completely honest. However, I looked through it a couple of times and it seems like it will work to me. I suggest you take this code and try to make it work. Give it a try.

```
//For every Cell on the board
for (int i = 0; i < key.length; i++){
    for (int a = 0; a < key[0].length; a++){

        //If it Is not a mine
        if (key[i][a] == 0){ 
            int count = 0;

            //Position of cells around key[i][a] relative to key[i][a]
            for (int x = -1; x < 2; x++){  
                for (int y = -1; y < 2; y++){ 

                    //Storing x and y test points
                    int testX = i + x;//testX = i-1, i, and i+1
                    int testY = i + y;//testY = i-1, y, and y+1

                    //If the testX and testY values are within the range of the array
                    if ((testX >= 0 && testX < key[0].length) && testY >= 0 && testY < key.length){

                        //If there is a mine
                        if (key[testX][testY] == 9){
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            key[i][a] = count;

            //count = 0; This is redundant. Line 7 count gets set to 0.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, if you have any questions on the above code, feel free to ask

Comment: it seems as if the increments on count don't make it to the end of the loops

Comment: You're totally right, my bad.

@Brian Lee I fixed that part of it. Still can't promise it works.

Comment: quick question, but in a 2d array, i in int[i][a] is the COLUMN, right?

Comment: Not in every 2D array. It really depends on your code. My code does work off of the assumption that the 'i' represents the current column.

Comment: could there possibly be a theoretical max length/width this program could process before getting overloaded?

Comment: I don't think so. I've created a new project, gone straight to the context.xml file, tried to resize and couldn't.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are misusing the `continue` statement, it will move the execution back to the `for` loop and therefore not complete the various checks to increment `count`.

In the `catch` statements you should do nothing instead.

Comment: This is true. If you delete all of your "continue" statements, you'll probably be fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(key[i-1][i-1] == 9){
```

This looks different from all your other ones, which have i and a.  This one uses i twice.  Maybe that's your problem?

Comment: And maybe you should use a for loop or something, so you aren't repeating basically the same thing 8 times.  That's how this sort of mistake can happen.

Comment: OH i didnt see that